# R character conversion

Tags: r

From an import, I have a date being read in as a factor:

```
user$registrationDate[1]
[1] "2004-07-23 14:19:32"
15551 Levels:  " "1" "2004-07-23 14:19:32" "2004-07-25 03:29:18" "2004-07-25 08:35:20" ... i10yo."
```

I convert it apparently successfully into a character vector

```
as.character(user$registrationDate[1])
[1] "\"2004-07-23 14:19:32\""
```

Whatever I try to strip off the leading and trailing quote, I still end up with a trailing quote (or something like it)

```
sub('"', "", as.character(user$registrationDate[10]), fixed=TRUE)
[1] "2004-09-12 22:39:21\""
```

I tried many variations of sub and keep getting the same result. Tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `?sub`: "sub replaces only the first occurrence of a pattern whereas gsub replaces all occurrences". So use `gsub` instead.